# Unable to connect to regular sites using IE7 in Wine

Tags: wine, ie

I have the latest version of Ubuntu installed one week back. I installed Wine and used PlayOnLinux to install IE7.

It is successfully installed. It connects to Bing, Google and does the searches, but when I directly enter urls like *mail.yahoo.com* and so on it gives message "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage"

Has any one seen this error and resolved this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use Winetricks to install extra dlls that are needed.

Comment: Especially `url.dll`.